# Unable to Deserialize a specific Json in C# desktop application

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize following Json. I am getting this Json from a server and have to use it on a desktop application

```
{
"panicForms": [{
    "name": "Name",
    "description": "Description",
    "title": "Title",
    "Image": "",
    "keyboardShortcut": "",
    "instructions": "Instructions",
    "submitButtonText": "",
    "label": "",
    "tooltip": "",
    "textColor": "Black",
    "backgroundColor": "Red",
    "textStyle": "Normal",
    "systemTrayEnabled": true,
    "fields": [{
            "eventField": "Name",
            "label": "Full Name",
            "type": "single selection",
            "required": true
        },
        {
            "eventField": "Age",
            "label": "age",
            "type": "single selection",
            "required": false
        }
    ]
}]
```

}

Created following objects

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
public class Field
{
    public string eventField { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public bool required { get; set; }
}

public class PanicForm
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string keyboardShortcut { get; set; }
    public string instructions { get; set; }
    public string submitButtonText { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string tooltip { get; set; }
    public string textColor { get; set; }
    public string backgroundColor { get; set; }
    public string textStyle { get; set; }
    public bool systemTrayEnabled { get; set; }
    public List<Field> fields { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<PanicForm> panicForms { get; set; }
}
```

and used tried following code to deserialize

```
var stuff1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PanicForm[]>(jsonString1);
```

&

```
var stuff1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PanicForm>>(jsonString1);
```

&

```
var stuff1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString1);
```

&

```
var stuff1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PanicForm>(jsonString1);
```

&

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString1);
```

but in the end getting the same error

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: s. Path '', line 0, position 0.'
```

detail is

```
        StackTrace  "   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)\r\n   at TestDynamicControls.Form1..ctor() in C:\\Alertus\\PanicUI\\TestDynamicControls\\TestDynamicControls\\Form1.cs:line 58\r\n   at TestDynamicControls.Program.Main() in C:\\Alertus\\PanicUI\\TestDynamicControls\\TestDynamicControls\\Program.cs:line 19"  string
```

Can any one help me in this solving this, thanks

Comment: The json is not an array, it is only a single `PanicForm`

Comment: @Alen.Toma following code also didn't work
var stuff1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PanicForm>(jsonString1);

Comment: The right way is told in a comment by the tool you used: // Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);

Comment: @LeandroBardelli , this was the first thing I tried but unfortunately threw the same exception.

Comment: Maybe you have some issue reading your json. But JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(x) must work.

Comment: I think the same than @Mate. Pretty sure your `jsonString1` value does not look like the provided one. Maybe you have some issues when reading the server response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the data in the example you exposed:

The right way is told in a comment by the tool you used:

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
```

Check this fiddle:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/vofLpq

For the classes:

```
public class Field
{
    public string eventField { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public bool required { get; set; }
}

public class PanicForm
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string keyboardShortcut { get; set; }
    public string instructions { get; set; }
    public string submitButtonText { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string tooltip { get; set; }
    public string textColor { get; set; }
    public string backgroundColor { get; set; }
    public string textStyle { get; set; }
    public bool systemTrayEnabled { get; set; }
    public List<Field> fields { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<PanicForm> panicForms { get; set; }
}
```

you have to deserialize:

```
    Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
```

with this references:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

If you are having data problems you should check your input first, you could use any json validator as: https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1):

To get a list , you can parse a json string, and after this to deserilize an array

```
List<PanicForm> panicForms = JObject.Parse(jsonString1)["panicForms"].ToObject<List<PanicForm>>();
```